# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection Single aggregate class instead of multiple separate constructor injections

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection

In my ASP.NET Core Web API I have several controllers which accept more than 4-5 parameters in their constructors and this doesn't look good to me. I'm thinking of creating an aggregate class which would have all the separate objects I frequently use.
I mean, for example, instead of this:

```
public SomeController : Controller
{
    public SomeController(
        IService1 service1,
        IService2 service2,
        Config1 config1,
        Config2 config2)
    {
    }
}
```

to write something like this:

```
// of course registered in DI services.AddSingleton<MyToolkit>()
public class MyToolkit 
{
    public MyToolkit(
        IService1 service1,
        IService2 service2,
        Config1 config1,
        Config2 config2)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IService1 Service1 { get; }
    public IService2 Service2 { get; }
    public Config1 Config1 { get; }
    public Config2 Config2 { get; }
}

public SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyToolkit _toolkit;
    public SomeController(MyToolkit toolkit) { _toolkit = toolkit; }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetSomething()
    {
        return _toolkit.Service1.GetSomething();
    }
}
```

Does this approach (MyToolkit class) violate any modern design principles? Is this approach considered anti-pattern?

Comment: The book [DIPP&P](https://cuttingedge.it/book/) (which I coauthored) contains a whole section ([section 6.1](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/12)) on the Constructor Over-Injection code smell. It presents several solutions, such as the [Facade Services refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/), [composites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), [domain events](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html), and [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First review if all those dependencies are really needed at the controller level.

Having many dependencies is usually a sign that the subject class is most likely doing too many things (SRP violation).

If those dependencies injected into the aggregate are just going to be exposed as properties then the controller and the aggregate is being disingenuous about what it explicitly needs to perform its function. (Explicit Dependency Principle)

If there is functionality happening the in the controller that uses those dependencies and should actually be in its own class then abstract that functionality and its dependencies out. (Separation of Concerns - SoC)

Your current approach based on the provided example is just kicking the can down the road and can be seen as a code smell.

Comment: In my case actually every controller depends on ILogger, some performance counter stuff, antifraud stuff, materialized appsettings.json objects and MediatR. I just thought why not to make and aggregate class that represents some kind of Repository of frequently used singleton objects. Singletons remain in the memory anyways, so no resources are wasted.

Comment: @TiberSeptim Those sound a lot like [cross-cutting concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern)

Comment: If you're using MediatR, are you sure you can't apply all these 'concerns' in a decorator or using MediatR's [behavior](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors)?

Comment: @Nkosi, OK, I guess my design violates the Explicit Dependencies principle.

Comment: @TiberSeptim for general exception logging you can abstract logging with exception filters and add code in your filter to log OnException and other scenarios.  That way you don't have to include an iLogger in every controller. It also removes all try-catch code. If your controller uses the logger as well for custom logging i.e: "Job done etc..." I'd argue the controller might not the place for that. I prefer controllers to be closer to proxy's with mappers and everything similar abstracted.